# Libcurl write data to array

Tags: c++, arrays, file-io, libcurl

I've really searched this. I've seen examples of how you can download and write data to a file with libcurl but I don't know how to write them to an array

that's the code I have so far:

```
static size_t write_data(void *ptr, size_t size, size_t nmemb, void *stream)
{

int written = fwrite(ptr, size, nmemb, (FILE *)stream);
return written;
}

int main(void)
{
CURL *curl_handle;
FILE *bodyfile;
static const char *headerfilename = "head.out";
FILE *headerfile;
static const char *bodyfilename = "body.out";

curl_global_init(CURL_GLOBAL_ALL);

/* init the curl session */
curl_handle = curl_easy_init();

/* set URL to get */
curl_easy_setopt(curl_handle, CURLOPT_URL,"http://example.com/");
/* no progress meter please */
curl_easy_setopt(curl_handle, CURLOPT_NOPROGRESS, 1L);

/* send all data to this function  */
curl_easy_setopt(curl_handle, CURLOPT_WRITEFUNCTION, write_data);

/* open the files */
headerfile = fopen(headerfilename,"w");
if (headerfile == NULL) {
    curl_easy_cleanup(curl_handle);
    return -1;
}
bodyfile = fopen(bodyfilename,"w");
if (bodyfile == NULL) {
    curl_easy_cleanup(curl_handle);
    return -1;
}

/* we want the headers to this file handle */
curl_easy_setopt(curl_handle,   CURLOPT_WRITEHEADER, headerfile);

/* we want the body to this file handle */
curl_easy_setopt(curl_handle, CURLOPT_WRITEDATA, bodyfile);

/* get it! */
curl_easy_perform(curl_handle);

/* close the header file */
fclose(headerfile);
fclose(bodyfile);
return 0;
}
```

Comment: hint (seeing your history): when asking a c++ related question, tag it, don't prepend "c++"

Comment: I agree to Kerrek, this is C not C++. You're not using any C++ feature there. It doesn't matter that your file is named .cpp or is being compiled by a C++-capable compiler, if there are no classes, templates & etc, it's just C.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It seems, what you need is described in the [libcurl documentation](http://curl.haxx.se/libcurl/c/curl_easy_setopt.html#CURLOPTWRITEFUNCTION):

> CURLOPT_WRITEFUNCTION
>
> Function pointer that should match the following prototype: size_t
>   function( char *ptr, size_t size, size_t nmemb, void *userdata); This
>   function gets called by libcurl as soon as there is data received that
>   needs to be saved. [...]

That is you have to implement a function with the signature

```
size_t my_array_write(char *ptr, size_t size, size_t nmemb, void *userdata);
```

And pass it to curl:

```
curl_easy_setopt(curl_handle, CURLOPT_WRITEFUNCTION, my_array_write);
```

However, I haven't tested it (and I am not aware of a simpler way to achieve this). See the [libcurl docs](http://curl.haxx.se/libcurl/c/) for more information.

Comment: Also you'll need to keep track of the offset you're writing to; for large resources my_array_write will be called many times by libcurl, and each time you have to append data to the end of the array. And, of course, to be careful you should also have somewhere the array size, and check the offset against it to avoid an overflow.

Comment: @Fabio that is correct :) Hence the reference to the documentation.